Why isn't the local rust documentation not opening?
I'm on the introduction part of the book The Rust Programming Language. More specifically, I'm trying to install rustup. Since my OS is the 64-bit Windows 11, I had to go to the rustup website for installation. Instead of using the download link, I opted to use the Linux on Windows option (since I already have Ubuntu 22.04.3 running as WSL).
I ran the command rustup doc on Powershell (running as admin). Instead of the doc being open, I got this message:
rustup doc
Opening docs in your browser
error: couldn't open browser: error spawning command(s) 'wslview, xdg-open': No such file or directory (os error 2)
Can someone explain to me why I'm getting this error? How can I solve this?
Ive googled the entire message I shared, but since I'm new to using any CLI or terminal simulator as my primary way of navigating my computer, I found the explanations a little hard to understand. I want to use this to understand better how OS and terminals work. If anyone can explain to me what and why exactly caused this error, I could figure all this out on my own in the future. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

You should rollback/remove your "update" and instead post as an answer to your own question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Check if the files wslview, xdg-open are located on the machine.  Most likely you do not have the path to the files set.  Powershell uses environmental variable PSModulePath to locate cmdlets.

https://superuser.com/questions/1262977/open-browser-in-host-system-from-windows-subsystem-for-linux  -> Install wslu and add export BROWSER=wslview to your $HOME/.bashrc (or equivalent if you use other shell)
